# How does vim define a sentence. How can I wrap a sentence as quickly as possible

Tags: python, vim

everyone.

I've used vim for 2 years. I find myself always want to wrap a sentence. For example in python:

```
class.method(http://v.youku.com/v_show/id_XNzc4MzE1NzQ4.html)
```

Now cusor is at the word

```
v_show
```

How can I wrap `http://v.youku.com/v_show/id_XNzc4MzE1NzQ4.html` with '' as quickly as possible, in other words, how can I specify the sentence.

I wonder how vim define a sentence.

Thanks!

Comment: `:h navigation` will blow your mind.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A sentence in vim must end in either a `.`, `!` or `?` followed by either the end of a line, or by a space or tab. See `:h sentence`. Therefor you cannot treat your line as a sentence.

However, you can treat `class.method(http://v.youku.com/v_show/id_XNzc4MzE1NzQ4.html)` as a vim `WORD` as it has no whitespaces. See `:h WORD`.

To surround the `WORD` in `"`'s in plain vim you could do: `ciW"`<kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>r</kbd>`""`.

As @Yosh has pointed out, what you probably wanted was `ci("`<kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>r</kbd>`""`.

You may also be interested in tpope's [surround.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround).

Comment: I think what @linuxie wants is `class.method("http://v.youku.com/v_show/id_XNzc4MzE1NzQ4.html")`, text object being `i)`. With surrond.vim, that'll be `ysi)"`. +1 for using `"` register.

Comment: @Yosh Opps, looks like I didn't read the question properly, you are probably right.

Comment: @brettanomyces Thanks all the same, I should refer to vim help first, by the way, what do you mean of ctrl-r ""?

Comment: `<C-r>{register}` inserts the content of `{register}`. `ci(` cuts what's between parentheses into the unnamed register, `"`, so `<C-r>"` inserts what you just cut. In other words, you remove some text, insert `"`, insert back the removed text, followed by another `"`.

Comment: @linuxie if you think this approach use too may keys you should try the alternative with [surround plugin](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround/), as noted in the answer (which you should probably [mark as accepted](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5235))